# how to execute playwright codegen with disabling web security

Tags: playwright

I was trying to run this command

```
npx playwright codegen <URL>
```

But its opening the browser with web security.

How to use codegen with disable-web-security as we do while launching chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that from the command line directly.

You need to call `page.pause()` from your script (where you already have started the browser without security), this will pause the script execution and open a new codegen window (in addition to the browser).

> If you would like to use codegen in some non-standard setup (for example, use `browserContext.route(url, handler[, options]))`, it is possible to call `page.pause()` that will open a separate window with codegen controls.

See https://playwright.dev/docs/cli/#codegen-with-custom-setup for an example.

Comment: thanks it worked. I used the same, recorded and copied the code.

Comment: Great to hear that! Would you then please so kind to upvote and accept the answer? Many thanks!